# Asp.net core disable change string in Uri

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Encoded string like this:

```
https://xx.yyy.ir/xx/ff/addUser?name=%d8%b3%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%85
```

But when I use Uri to convert it to a URL and send it

```
result = "https://xx.yyy.ir/xx/ff/addUser?name=%d8%b3%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%85"
var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(result.ToString()),
                
                
};

var response = await client.GetAsync("");
```

it send this request :

```
https://xx.yyy.ir/xx/ff/addUser?name=سلام
```

why this happen? how to prevent from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's causing your problem: `new Uri(result.ToString())`

Let's try to do this in a proper manner and see what happens.

```
var builder = new UriBuilder("https://xx.yyy.ir/xx/ff/addUser") { Port = -1 };

var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
query["name"] = "سلام";
builder.Query = query.ToString();

using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(builder.ToString());
```

`builder.ToString()` returns `https://xx.yyy.ir/xx/ff/addUser?name=%d8%b3%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%85`

So basically, the above code boils down to this:

```
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://xx.yyy.ir/xx/ff/addUser?name=%d8%b3%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%85");
```

Tested and verified on my computer.

Comment: Thanks,As you say I used `var httpClient = new HttpClient();var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(result.ToString());` but my encoding issue dose not solved.!!!

Comment: Let me know if you need more information. I desperately need a solution to this problem.

Comment: @Amir133: Updated my answer, can you try?

Comment: @Amir133: Does `var response = await client.GetAsync("https://xx.yyy.ir/xx/ff/addUser?name=%d8%b3%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%85");` work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your reply is completely correct but unfortunately it seems to have a problem somewhere else in my work.

Comment: @Amir133: Please let me know if I can contribute.

Comment: I have a field called Check Sam, which is generated based on URL. When I want to calculate its value, the URL letters are small, but when I capture the request with Fidller, some URL letters are Capital. The string on which I make the checkmate:`https://xx.yyy.ir/xx/ff/addUser?name=%d8%b3%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%85&checksum=92330ceb9735801558dfd1c261fefd97f1615d7d`.   The string I receive through Fiddler`https://xx.yyy.ir/xx/ff/addUser?name=%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85&checksum=92330ceb9735801558dfd1c261fefd97f1615d7d` please compare`%D8` and `%d8`. how can I prevent from this problem?

Comment: This test is passing on my computer. Can you do it in your code? `Assert.AreEqual("%d8%b3%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%85", "%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85".ToLower());` Check sums are also passing equality test.